# AltBeacon keep scanning when the app is closed

Tags: java, android, arraylist, bluetooth, ibeacon

I am using the `AltBeacon` beacon scanning library to scan beacons. I start the beacon scanner in a service, which gets called by a broadcast receiver on boot or when bluetooth state changes. When I open the app and exit it again, the `BeaconHandler` gets killed and restarts because the beacon service calls the broadcast receiver again.

The problem is I don't want the beacon scanner to get reset when I exit my app, because I save all the scanned beacons in a `ArrayLis`t and need to track movements of a user in a building. So when I exit the app my `Arraylist` gets cleared and I lose track of the movement of the user.

My background service:

```
public class BeaconService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "BeaconService";

    private BeaconHandler beaconHandler;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate()");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand()");

        beaconHandler = BeaconHandler.getInstance(getApplicationContext(),
                BeaconHandler1.getInstance(getApplicationContext()),
                BeaconHandler2.getInstance(getApplicationContext()));

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy()");

        beaconHandler.stopListening();

        sendBroadcast(new Intent(this, BluetoothReceiver.class));
    }
}
```

My broadcast receiver:

```
public class BluetoothReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("BluetoothReceiver", "onReceive()");

        if (BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(context).checkAvailability()) {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, BeaconService.class));
        } else {
            context.stopService(new Intent(context, BeaconService.class));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the beacon handler is a singleton class, so there is only one instance running at the time. Is there a way to prevent the beacon scanner to get reset and to clear my `ArrayList` when the app gets closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot stop the app from getting killed by the user or by the operating system if memory is low.

The solution is to save your app state in nonvolatile storage, then read it back when the service starts up.  [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) is a good storage mechanism if your data are simple.

Keep in mind that you cannot control when your app gets killed, or rely on a callback when it happebs, so you need to save data regularly.

Comment: Hi, yeah I know I cannot stop the app from getting killed when it is low on memory. I already thought of using shared preferences, but there are quite alot of entries in the list to be saved, and idk if that will work out as it will either take up alot of space or take a long time to write and read all the data back

Comment: Are you saying you do not care if your app is force closed or closed by the OS, you just want the service to keep running and not restart on manual relaunch if the user hits tlthe back button to close?

Comment: Just when the user exits the app and closes it in tge recents app list

Comment: The problem is that closing an app from the task list kills all running services just like if it is closed for low memory.  This leaves you with the answer I provided.  If SharedPreferences won't work, you might consider a SQLite database or even a flat file with serialized java objects.  But you need nonvolatile storage to solve this.